# Choose What BeautifulSoup .text method prints?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using BeautifulSoup to webscrape data from a website. In my main function, I'm printing out the all "strong" elements from a HTML file, but I would like to filter out some text that I don't want to print.

```
x = "abcdef"
for i,strong in enumerate(html.select("strong")):
    print(i,strong.text)
```

In this scenario, I would like to check if x is in strong.text, and then print it out if the text does not contain it.

Comment: just add an `if` before `print`. `if x in strong.text:`

Comment: Was first thing I tried, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most finder methods in BeautifulSoup based off `bs4.element.SoupStrainer` take an optional text argument.

When this argument is a function, it is passed the matching node (`bs4.element.NavigableString`). *e.g.*

```
matched_nodes = html.findAll('strong', text=lambda n: x in n.lower())
for i, strong in enumerate(matched_nodes):
    print(i, matched_nodes)
```